# How to get all CPU information

Tags: java, android, cpu

I need these following information which will return like that:

```
CPU Model: Quad Core 1.19 GHz Qualcomm Technologies, Inc MSM8216
Clock Speed: 300.0 MHz - 1.10 GHz
Core: 4
Architecture: Krait 400
Process: 280 nm
CPU Load: 15%
CPU Governor: interactive
Kernel Version: 3.18.14-8252493
Kernel Architecture: aarch64
```

Comment: Accept the below answer if it tends to be right or have help you in someway .

Answer (score 0):

```
Log.i("TAG", "SERIAL: " + Build.SERIAL);
Log.i("TAG","MODEL: " + Build.MODEL);
Log.i("TAG","ID: " + Build.ID);
Log.i("TAG","Manufacture: " + Build.MANUFACTURER);
Log.i("TAG","brand: " + Build.BRAND);
Log.i("TAG","type: " + Build.TYPE);
Log.i("TAG","user: " + Build.USER);
Log.i("TAG","BASE: " + Build.VERSION_CODES.BASE);
Log.i("TAG","INCREMENTAL " + Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL);
Log.i("TAG","SDK  " + Build.VERSION.SDK);
Log.i("TAG","BOARD: " + Build.BOARD);
Log.i("TAG","BRAND " + Build.BRAND);
Log.i("TAG","HOST " + Build.HOST);
Log.i("TAG","FINGERPRINT: "+Build.FINGERPRINT);
Log.i("TAG","Version Code: " + Build.VERSION.RELEASE);
```

You can find more here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html.

Some information that need to check SDK level before using.

Comment: It seems to be OS information rather than CPU information.